How to call a component from a controller file?
I'm new to ember js, It may feel like a dumb question, but still:
I've already defined a component say {{pq-component}}, it works fine, when called from a .hbs file.
But when I try to call it from a .js file like this
$('#'+block_id+"_toppager").find('.div-import-box').html('<div>{{pq-component}}</div>');

The {{pq-component}} is displaying as a 'String', rather than the rendering the contents of the actual component itself.
So, any suggestions to render the content of {{pq-component}} from the controller file, would be helpful.
I'm using "ember 2.1"
When I try to call it from a .js file like this
$('#'+block_id+"_toppager").find('.div-import-box').html('<div>{{pq-component}}</div>');

I expected to render the contents of the {{pq-component}} to display, but its displaying it as 'pq-component' - the string itslef.

Why are you trying to access a component from a controller? I'm almost certain that this isn't the best or Embery way to achieve whatever your objective is. Also if you are new to Ember why are you starting with such an old version? And finally I would avoid using JQuery in Ember if you can as that's going to make upgrading harder for you later on.

Hi @Caltor, this project was already started few years back, and they have been using this ember version, so there are limited options to migrate the code to the latest version. And yeah, calling an component from a controller, seems odd. But I just need to know is there a way to do it?

I'm not aware of a way. I'm not even sure you could count on the component having been created at the point your code executes. I really think you should tell us what you are trying to achieve and we can see if there is a more "embery" way of doing it rather than you trying to fight the framework

another way to think about this is that JS doesn't render to the DOM -- but templates do

can you describe the higher level task you're trying to accomplish? perhaps we could help with that?
